# Set specific datacontext to a DatePicker in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm newbie in c# and xaml. I've created a singleton and I'm trying to bind properties to my objects.

If I add datacontext in code-behind, everything works fine. But i can't find the way to add datacontext directly in xaml code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Filtre Filtre = Filtre.GetInstance();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DateDebut.DataContext = Filtre;
    }
}
```

I would like to set the data context in xaml instead of code-behind like this

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 6">
    <TextBlock Text="Du" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <DatePicker Name="DateDebut" Width="100" SelectedDate="{Binding DateDebut}" DataContext=???/>
</StackPanel>
```

Singleton

```
public class Filtre: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Filtre? _instance = null;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    private DateTime _dateDebut;
    private DateTime _dateFin;

    // On déclare le constructeur privé pour ne pas pouvoir créer d'instance de Filtre dans le code
    private Filtre()
    { 
        DateDebut = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        DateFin = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public static Filtre GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new Filtre();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public DateTime DateDebut 
    {
        get { return _dateDebut; }
        set
        {
            _dateDebut = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateFin
    {
        get { return _dateFin; }
        set
        {
            _dateFin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

If someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: First: why do you want to set the DataContext in xaml? Best way would be to set the DataContext when instantiating the window. The xaml should use `Binding` like you did with `SelectedDate`.

Comment: Ok so the good way to do it is in code-behind rather than in xaml ? So I will set it like this. Just for my personal knowledge, how could this be done in xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" DataContext="{x:Static local:Singleton.Instance}"></DatePicker>
```

and the singleton:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return new DateTime(2020, 1, 1); }
        set {}
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work. When I add this code `DataContext="{x:Static local:Filtre}"`, I'm having an error `Member "Filtre" not found`. I've added the code for singleton. The singleton and the MainWindow are on 2 different namesapces.

Comment: Please post your code.